# TypeError: Network Request Failed at XMLHttpRequest in react native app

Tags: react-native, graphql

I'm using react native fetch to make a post http request with graphql data to a graphql server endpoint. When starting up my graphql server and calling fetch with a POST in my react native app, I'm getting the following error:

**TypeError: Network Request Failed at XMLHttpRequest in react native app**

**Request code**

```
let graphqlServer = config.graphQLServerUrl;
const graphQLFetcher = (graphQLParams, requestType, token) => {
let body = null; //earlier i used var body =' '; //blank value --null & blank makes a different
let headers = null;
body = graphQLParams; 

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
 };

  return  fetch(graphqlServer, {
    method: requestType,
    headers: headers,
    body: graphQLParams,
  });
};
```

**Data**
  qraphQLParams

        `query {
          login(userName: ${credentials.userName}, passWord: ${credentials.passWord})
        }`
,

Any ideas?

Comment: I`m facing the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: JSON.stringify the body. (body is the graphql query itself)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work by simply JSON.stringify the body of the request.

So..

```
graphQLParams = `query login{
      login(input: {userName: "${obj.input.userName}", passWord: "${obj.input.passWord}" }) {
        token
      }
    }
  ` 

body = JSON.stringify({
  query: graphQLParams
 });
```

Comment: in my case I'm using relay. I don't use some sort of body. :|